# values claiming not to be equal even when they are

Tags: java

I'm making a simple lotto game but when I enter some numbers and set the dice to only have 1 (100% chance of winning) I still get the losing outcome.
Also how can I make the bad luck statement print only once? I know you can make a boolean value and such but is there an easier way?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    int randnum = 0;
    Random gen = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers to be drawn");
    int print = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers on dice");
    int dice = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your lucky numbers");
    int[] numbers = new int[print];
    for(int i=0; i<print;i++){
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    for(int counter=1; counter<=print;counter++){
        randnum = 1+gen.nextInt(dice);
        System.out.println(randnum + " ");
        System.out.println();
        if (randnum == num){
            System.out.println("Winner winner chicken dinner!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Bad luck!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `num`?

Comment: Instead of `num` you want `numbers[counter-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never changing the value of num. It is always 0. For what i understand, what you want is to check if the numbers you enter are the same and in the same order of appearance, so you'll need to check `if (randnum == numbers[counter-1])`

If you want to print only once the String `"Bad luck!"` the best way to do it is with a `boolean`. There is another, **terrible** way to do it, which is using `break;`, but the world will end if you do that. Another thing you can do is set `counter = print+1`, which is practically the same as using `break`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple. You are not comparing randnum to the right variable. What you have to do is to replace your condition by :

```
       if (randnum == numbers[counter - 1]){
            System.out.println("Winner winner chicken dinner!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Bad luck!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because, num is always 0 (it is not changed), and randnum is always >= 1 since you call   randnum = 1+gen.nextInt(dice);

I think, you need to add in line 22:

```
 num = numbers[counter-1];
```

it should be:

```
package findarray2;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    int randnum = 0;
    Random gen = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers to be drawn");
    int print = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter desired numbers on dice");
    int dice = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your lucky numbers");
    int[] numbers = new int[print];
    for(int i=0; i<print;i++){
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    for(int counter=1; counter<=print;counter++){
        num = numbers[counter-1];
        randnum = 1+gen.nextInt(dice);
        System.out.println(randnum + " ");
        System.out.println();
    if (randnum == num){
            System.out.println("Winner winner chicken dinner!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Bad luck!");
        }
    }
}
```